# Save upgrade dialog option other than in *.v12.suo file in vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, upgrade, suo

I recently upgrade a solution to vs2013, however, multiple projects depended on some older libraries, hence I had to leave them with the Platform Toolset configured to `Visual Studio 2010 (v100)`.

However, every time I cloned the repository on a new system, it would prompt me to upgrade those projects to vs2013. After a bit of digging I discovered that it saves those prompt options in the .v12.suo file.  I'm well aware of the suo functionality, and all the user settings it saves, and therefore why it should not be in source control. But, can not for the life of me figure out why they would choose to save the upgrade dialog options in there.

In my mind, once i choose not to upgrade a project, and put the new solution in source control, other developers should not be asked the same question. In fact, it's quite dangerous, if someone were to upgrade, it would no longer compile.

Is there a way to save the upgrade dialog options in the solution or project file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, this is a known issue in vs2013 as described by this Visual Studio issue.

- [VS 2013 Keeps upgrade information in the Solution User Options (.v12.suo) file](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/871523/vs-2013-keeps-upgrade-information-in-the-solution-user-options-v12-suo-file)

Given that it is an issue, not sure there is any other way to save that information other than in the suo.  I guess for now, just have to wait and see if they come out with a fix.